# Functions commonly listed in chemistry character tables for point groupss.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Is there a good resource for explaining why certain functions are associated with certain irreducible reps listed in character tables for common chemistry point groups?
I can reason through the majority of them using techniques such as the finding the trace of the matrix representation for rotations in a 2D vector spaces with basis functions $(x^2-y^2,xy)$ which would be $2Cos2\theta$. But there are still are still others that seem confusing to me like finding which rep which would be associated with $(2z^2-x^2-y^2,x^2-y^2)$ in the tetrahedral symmetry group. It seems to me that $1+Cos2\theta$ would give the trace for rotations in this group yielding 1/2 for C3 rotations. However, -1 listed in table.